# Material Icons Bug - Icons become chars like so "S" "T" "A" "R" after HTML2Canvas runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

Before my html2canvas/jspdf script runs, my material-icon that the dialog was opened from looks as it should on the page. This icon opens a dialog menu with export to excel and pdf features. When the pdf option is clicked and the scrip below is ran, the icon used to open the dialog gets recoded by one of following two libraries, jspdf or html2canvas. It turns the text inside the Md-icon tags into individual charterers on a line of their own. I hope someone has ran into something similar.

```
<md-icon>assignment_late</md-icon>
```

After the dialog is opened ->SaveToPDF/clickeEvent ->Script is ran then the material icon disappears because the html inside looks as so

```
<md-icon>
"a"
"s"
"s"
"i"
"n"
"g"
"m"
"e"
"n"
"t"
"_"
"l"
"a"
"t"
"e"
</md-icon>
```

Script for HTML2Canvas/JSPDF

```
html2canvas(source, {
canvas:canvas,
onrendered: function (canvas) {
//! MAKE YOUR PDF
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a3');
for (var i = 0; i <= source.clientHeight / 980; i++) {
//! This is all just html2canvas stuff
var srcImg = canvas;
var sX = 0;        //sourceImage x coord
var sY = 0;  // start 980 pixels down for every new page
var sWidth = srcImg.width;  //source image width
var sHeight = srcImg.height; //source image height        
var dX = 0;        //destination canvas x coord
var dY = 0;        //destination canvas y coord
var dWidth = srcImg.width;  //destination canvas width
var dHeight = srcImg.height; //destination canvas height
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var hours = today.getHours();
var minutes = today.getMinutes();
var previewPane = document.getElementById('previewPane');
var title = edc.exportTitle;
window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
onePageCanvas.setAttribute('width', 900);
onePageCanvas.setAttribute('height', 980);
var ctx = onePageCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(srcImg, sX, sY, sWidth, sHeight, dX, dY, dWidth, dHeight);
// document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var canvasDataURL = onePageCanvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);

var width = onePageCanvas.width;
var height = onePageCanvas.clientHeight;

//! If we're on anything other than the first page,
// add another page
if (i > 0) {
pdf.addPage(612, 791); //8.5" x 11" in pts (in*72)
}
//! now we declare that we're working on that page
pdf.setPage(i + 1);
//! now we add content to that page!
var left = (900 - dWidth) * 0.5;
var top = (980 - dHeight) * 0.5;

pdf.addImage(canvasDataURL, 'PNG', left, top, width, height);
}
```

Comment: guessing its a ligature in the web font. can you set the webfont?

Comment: I think you might be on to something, i'm testing now to see if the font of the icon has effect on this.

Comment: I now have the same problem as you. The icons are rendered incorrectly on chrome.

Comment: I had solved this by simply upgrading Html2Canvas to the latest version, i believe version 5.0 alpha .https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases